# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 142.251.10.108:465 Nodemailer ejs render | localhost

Tags: node.js, express

Thank you for your valuable time.
I was using nodemailer to send mail on Gmail account.

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var ejs = require("ejs");

const viewpath = __dirname + '/template/';
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true, // use SSL
    auth: {
        user: 'sample@gmail.com',
        pass: 'passs'
    }, 
});

 ejs.renderFile(viewpath + "test.ejs", { name: req.body.first_name }, function (err, data) {
 if (err) {
   console.log(err);
 } else {
  var mainOptions = {
    from: 'sample@gmail.com',  // sender address
    to: 'mymail@gmail.com',   // list of receivers
    subject: 'Subject',
    html: data
  };
  transporter.sendMail(mainOptions, function (err, info) {
   if (err) {
    console.log(err);
   } else {
    console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
   }
 });
}
});
```

Got error in console

[Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 142.251.10.108:465
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1159:16) {
errno: -4078,
code: 'ESOCKET',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '142.251.10.108',
port: 465,
command: 'CONN'
}][1]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your ISP provider or network provider block 465 destination port, make sure you access this port and check your network access

```sh
→ telnet 142.251.10.108 465
Trying 142.251.10.108...
Connected to 142.251.10.108.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

```sh
→ telnet smtp.gmail.com 465
Trying 108.177.14.108...
Connected to smtp.gmail.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```